# Problem with parser (IndexError: list index out of range)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Please help me with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/parser.py", line 14, in <module>
    for i in title[0].text:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

max_page = 6

pages = []

for x in range(1, max_page + 1):
    pages.append( requests.get("https://stopgame.ru/review/new/stopchoice/p" +  str(x) )  )
for r in  pages:
    html = BS(r.content, "html.parser")

    for el in html.select(".lent-block"):
        title = el.select(".lent-block > a")
        for i in title[0].text:
         title.text[0](title)
```

Comment: That means that your title list is empty, Why not check the content of `title`

Comment: Welcome to SO! `title = el.select(".lent-block > a")` is returning an empty list, so  `[][0]` is out of bounds. What is your expected output? Are you trying to get the title text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by your variable name that you want to get the title of each game. If so, you can target `.lent-title > a` directly. `.lent-block > a` gives you an empty list because `>` specifies an immediate child, not any descendent. `lent-block a` would give you all descendents.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

max_page = 6

for i in range(max_page):
    page = requests.get(f"https://stopgame.ru/review/new/stopchoice/p{i + 1}")
    html = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

    for el in html.select(".lent-title > a"):
        print(el.text)
```

Output:

```
Disco Elysium: Обзор
Dragon Quest XI S: Echoes of an Elusive Age - Definitive Edition: Обзор
Outer Wilds: Обзор
Baba Is You: Обзор
Apex Legends: Обзор
Mario & Luigi: Bowser's Inside Story + Bowser Jr.'s Journey: Обзор
Protocol: Обзор
Dead Cells: Обзор
...
```